# What's the correct pronunciation of "species"?

Tags: pronunciation

There are two pronunciations in my dictionary for **species**:

> spiːʃiːz, spiːsiːz

Which one is correct? Or both can be used?

Comment: I find questions about "correct pronunciation" even less meaningful than questions about "correct style." Yes, a lot of people think that something should be one way—but with accents, dialects, and simple preference, there are many more *actual* pronunciations than those you'll see in any dictionary. while writing can be formal or informal, pronunciation is far more nebulous.

Comment: @JasonBassford I appreciate if you could suggest the pronunciation, which is more widely acceptable. The reason why I asked this question is I wanted to learn more understandable pronunciation of this word. I encountered a similar case before. I used to pronounce *sugar* as su-gar (no one seemed to understand it), but actually it should be shu-gar. So, I just want to make sure I can get it correct this time.

Comment: I have no idea what the pronunciation "should" be. (Only how I've always heard it.) Mine was more of a meta comment—and probably not specifically helpful to you, so I apologize for that. (That's why I didn't put it in an actual answer. Especially since I see there already is one.)

Comment: Either pronunciation can be used, in American English or in British English. Related ELU question: [Are the different pronunciations of “species” regional differences?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/114807)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the USA both are used equally. But the spiːʃiːz is considered British.
So it comes down to a matter of taste.

- SPEE-shees [spiːʃiːz ] British
- SPEE-sees [spiːsiːz] American

You must have the Macmillan dictionary. They tend to put both.